# Google API Explorer: Where is the "fields" parameter editor?

Tags: google-apis-explorer

The API explorer used to have a handy feature that let you "build" a fields parameter by checking the parts of the struct you wanted included. I found this useful, but it is no longer on the documentation pages with the API requests themselves. Where did this go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It still exists in the standalone APIs Explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer.

It hasn't been added to the in-page APIs Explorer yet.